# How to round down float numbers in Postgres 13 to two decimal places for a computed column

Tags: sql, postgresql, rounding

I am trying to use this SQL to extract some derived values from a table. However when I try to ROUND the value that I get from

```
(COUNT(id) / DATE_PART('day', MAX(raised_date) - MIN(raised_date)))
```

I get an error that says:

> ROUND(COUNT(id) / DATE_PART('day', MAX(raised_date) - ...
> ^
> No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

```
SELECT 
    DATE_PART('day', MAX(raised_date) - MIN(raised_date)) AS date_diff, 
    COUNT(id) AS total,
    CASE 
        WHEN DATE_PART('day', MAX(raised_date) - MIN(raised_date)) > 0
            THEN ROUND(COUNT(id) / DATE_PART('day', MAX(raised_date) - MIN(raised_date)), 2)
            ELSE 0
    END AS newtiketsoveralldaysopen
FROM 
    public.tickets 
WHERE 
    company_id IN ('bd3986f8-27ec-41e7-848a-7da5df704f1f', 'a5104c5e-b4b7-4ab6-8ad4-e1fcdc3c48b1')
```

If I don't use the round I get the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because [ROUND](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-math.html) function allow `numeric` type values in the first parameter.

> round(v numeric, s int)

You can try `CAST` value as `numeric` before you used `ROUND` function.

```
SELECT DATE_PART('day', MAX(raised_date) - MIN(raised_date)) as date_diff, COUNT(id) as 
 total,
 CASE 
 WHEN DATE_PART('day', MAX(raised_date) - MIN(raised_date)) > 0
 THEN ROUND(COUNT(id) / DATE_PART('day', MAX(raised_date) - MIN(raised_date)::numeric), 2)
  ELSE 0
  END
  AS newtiketsoveralldaysopen
 FROM public.tickets 
 WHERE company_id IN ('bd3986f8-27ec-41e7-848a-7da5df704f1f','a5104c5e-b4b7-4ab6-8ad4-e1fcdc3c48b1')
```

we can try to use `pg_typeof` to see the type of columns as below query.

```
SELECT pg_typeof(COUNT(*)::numeric),
       pg_typeof(COUNT(*)),
       pg_typeof(DATE_PART('day',MAX(create_time) - MIN(create_time)))
FROM T

pg_typeof   pg_typeof   pg_typeof
numeric     bigint      double precision
```

Your query try to `ROUND` which first parameter is `double precision` but `ROUND` function only support `numeric` in the first parameter.

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9a7d35565b51b2ebcb78accd0f6ba691)